# Titanium Alloy compile failed to install device Android

Tags: android, titanium

first time i try to run my first application when i made with titanium, and then i tray to install my application to my device from titanium studio. i have changed my device to debugging mode and then i try install my application to my device from titanium studio but i get this message error from console:

```
[INFO] logfile = C:\Users\user\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\DStray\build.log
[DEBUG] C:\Users\zakki.a\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.2.GA\android\builder.py install DStray C:\KANTOR\tools\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk C:\Users\user\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\DStray com.dstray.user 4
[INFO] plugin=C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\plugins\ti.alloy\1.0\plugin.py
[INFO] Detected compiler plugin: ti.alloy/1.0
[INFO] alloy app found at C:\Users\user\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\DStray\app
[INFO] Executing Alloy compile:
[INFO]   alloy.cmd compile C:\Users\user\My Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\DStray\app --no-colors --config platform=android,version=8,simtype=none,devicefamily=none,deploytype=test,
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.


[ERROR] Alloy compile failed
```

can anybody help me why this happen ?what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to create a new mobile project (right after a fresh Titanium Studio install) I was getting the following error message:

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I had Node.JS Version: v0.8.22 version installed.

Upgrading Node.JS (http://nodejs.org/) to the most recent Version: v0.10.9 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

did you install nodeJS on your computer?

Comment: This answer should be a comment